# The Activity restart after saving data in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, android-activity, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to save user information in Firebase Database but a strange behavior happens that make the Save button to restart the same activity not the Intent that i made for the next activity .

```
 public void userData () {
    user.setFName(Fname.getText().toString());
    user.setLName(Lname.getText().toString());
    user.setEmail(Email.getText().toString());
    user.setAddress(userAddress.getText().toString());
    user.setPassword(UserInfo.getString("Password", ""));
    user.setID(CicID.getText().toString());
    user.setUsername(Usnm.getText().toString());
    if (bAdmn.isChecked()) user.setMajor("Business Administrator");
    if (BTech.isChecked()) user.setMajor("Business Tech");
    if (masscom.isChecked()) user.setMajor("Mass Com");
    if (Eng.isChecked()) user.setMajor("Engineering");

    final String us = user.getUsername();
    Log.i("Username", us);
    MyDatabase1.child("USERS").child(us).setValue(user);
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , chooseCoursesActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

that is the method for save button , Note that i want to update the user information in a profile Activity if the user wants to change his First name or Last name or something .
But after Clicking save button , the data is saved correctly but the intent never done . it recreate the same Activity .
in the Login activity there is aLogin button which checks username and password then attempt to log in based on data ,if login successful it goes to that Profile Activity .
Save button in Profile Activity re Do the method in Login button in Login Activity which checks everything and goes to Profile Activity which what causing the Re Create Problem .
Here is the code for login button :

```
    MyDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    MyDatabase.child("USERS").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            boolean exists = false;

            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                final Map<String, Object> model = (Map<String, Object>) child.getValue();

                if (model.get("username").equals(Username.getText().toString())) {
                    exists = true;
                    Log.i("USername"," Correct");


                    if(exists){
                        MyDatabase.child("USERS").orderByChild("username").equalTo(Username.getText().toString())

                                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                for (DataSnapshot child :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                    Log.i("Password",child.getValue().toString());
                                   Log.i( "Password",child.child("password").toString());
                                    if(password.getText().toString().equals(child.child("password").getValue())){
                                        Log.i("LOGIN","Success");
                                         loginsuccessful = true ;

                                    if(loginsuccessful){

                                        saveCredntials(Username.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());


                                        Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                                        i2.putExtra("loginStats",IsLoggedIn);
                                        i2.putExtra("Username",Un);

                                        i2.putExtra("Password",Pw);


                                        startActivity(i2);
                                        finish();}
                                    }else{
                                        Log.i("LOGIN","Failed");
                                        loginsuccessful= false ;

                                    }

                                }

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    break;

                }else {
                    Log.i("LOGIN","FAiled");

                }

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Sorry for making this too long but i dont know the problem .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just solved this problem! According to your case, please **avoid** using `addValueEventListener`, because it will listen to all changes you make to the database. That's why every time you make any change to the database, the code in the `addValueEventListener` (startActivity) will be executed no matter you call that login function or not.

My suggestion is using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener` (Make sure you change **ALL** the `addValueEventListener` in your Android project to `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`), or you can even remove the listener if you don't really need it. I don't know if it is a good design, but it should be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Avoid putting startActivity on a firebase listener. startActivity execute every time a value is added or removed from firebase database.